# Volume in spherical units

Tags: volume

- I'm working on Cavendish's original analysis of his experiment. Cavendish does not use equations or standard units. For instance, he states the weight of the lead weights by taking the weight of a sphere of water of 1 foot in diameter as unit. He says, the weight weighs 10.64 times the weight of a water sphere of 1 foot diameter.
- To calculate the weight of the earth he uses the definition of density, as, `density = weight/volume` (Cavendish does not use mass). Then he uses the relation `Force :: weight x inverse square of distance` to calculate the forces.
- This far I understand. But, Cavendish states his final result by skipping several steps. Luckily, in the book that I'm using the editor, included a footnote explaining the missing steps.
- My question is, in the footnote, he says, "the volume of the earth in spherical units is (41,800,000)^3..." But, 41,800,000 feet is the diameter of the earth. I thought (radius)^3 would be the volume. Can you explain why he is using (diameter)^3 for volume and not (radius)^3?

  [A copy of the original page.](http://cavendish-deneyi.com/pdf/cavendish-volume.pdf)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687017/volume-in-spherical-units)

Cavendish uses as his unit a sphere 1 foot in `diameter`, not 1 foot in `radius`.